# Digital Root (repeated digital sum) code issue

Tags: javascript, debugging, math

> Question : Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has
> more than one digit, continue reducing in this way until a
> single-digit number is produced. The input will be a non-negative
> integer. Ex- 16  -->  1 + 6 = 7    942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15  -->  1 +
> 5 = 6 132189  -->  1 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 8 + 9 = 24  -->  2 + 4 = 6 493193
> -->  4 + 9 + 3 + 1 + 9 + 3 = 29  -->  2 + 9 = 11  -->  1 + 1 = 2

```
function digitalroot(n) {
    let a = n; 
    var sum = 0;
    while(a >= 1){
      sum += a % 10;
      a = Math.trunc(a/10)
    }
    if(sum > 9){
      digitalroot(sum)
    } 
    console.log("Print")
    console.log(sum)
    return sum
}
```

I tried above code but not getting correct output with below called input
With this two inputs passed in function: (16), (456)

O/P:

```
Print
7
Print
6
Print
15
```

Please help me, I am new to JavaScript

Comment: Hello @Abhishek did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to return value from function call inside that sum>9 condition.

check recursion here : [w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_recursion.asp)

```js
function digitalroot(n) {
    let a = n; 
    var sum = 0;
    while(a >= 1){
      sum += a % 10;
      a = Math.trunc(a/10)
    }
    if(sum > 9){
      return digitalroot(sum)
    } 
    return sum
}
console.log(digitalroot(493193));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this working example

```js
function digitalroot(n){
console.log(`Value of n = ${n}`)
var digits = (""+n).split("");
for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) { 
digits[i] = +digits[i]; 
}
var finalVal = digits

let result = finalVal.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
console.log(`Final Value with list ${result}`)
}

digitalroot(289)
```